# How to create a table in redshift that contains the data related to the inner join of 2 or 3 other tables?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

So I have 3 tables in AWS Redshift, I would like to create another table, that contains data of inner join of these 3 tables. Can I use the **CREATE TABLE AS** statemnt for this purpose ?

ex :

```
CREATE TABLE AS table_name 
SELECT a.c1, a.c2,b.c3,c.c4
FROM  table1 a
Inner Join table2 b 
ON a.c1 = b.c1
Inner Join table3 c
ON b.c5 = c.c5;
```

Would the above work ? If not, what would be the best way to go about this ?

Lastly are views realised in Redshift ? I mean, would it be created in the database, or will it be create temporary for the duration of the query ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to run it? It should work.  The view is not physically materialized; the query that defines the view is run every time the view is referenced in a query

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_AS.html